# static variable in c language

Tags: c, static, initialization, local

Does static variable initialize only one time? does it ignore its initialize statement static int i=1, so it won't set it to 1 again so does it read it only first time then it ignores? how does it this work. if function called again and again, can anyone explain this?
Output: 123

```
#include<stdio.h>

void  increment();  
int main() 
{ 
    increment(); 
    increment(); 
    increment(); 
} 

void  increment() 
{ 
    static int i = 1 ; 
    printf("%d",i); 
    i=i+1; 
}
```

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: I find it interesting that you have a minimal example that shows that this is exactly how it works. And still you ask the question, like you don't believe it. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard *5.1.2 Execution environments)

> 1. ... All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to
>    their initial values) before program startup.

A function local static variable keeps its values between function calls.

So the program will output

```
123
```

Answer (score 1):

As a mental model of what is happening, your `increment` function works as if it was rewritten as:

```
static int foo_i = 1;
void  increment() 
{ 
    printf("%d",foo_i); 
    foo_i=foo_i+1; 
}
```

Naturally there won't exist a variable named `foo_i`, and if the compiler does that kind of rewriting it will use a unique name for `foo_i` that doesn't pollute the namespace of valid c-identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared as `static` are initialized once at program startup.  When a function with a `static` variable is called a subsequent time, the value is retained from the prior call.

In this particular case, the first call to `increment` prints "1", then "2" for the second call, then "3" for the third call.